# Overriding function from the modal.js file

Tags: magento2, javascript, modal-popup

How can I override a function from the modal.js file in the path `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/modal.js` ?

In this file, line 307, is a function with name closeModal() that I want to overwrite in my module `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/model/modal.js`

This is the original function:

```
 closeModal: function () {
            var that = this;

            this._removeKeyListener();
            this.options.isOpen = false;
            this.modal.one(this.options.transitionEvent, function () {
                that._close();
            });
            this.modal.removeClass(this.options.modalVisibleClass);

            if (!this.options.transitionEvent) {
                that._close();
            }

            return this.element;
        },
```

In my `modal.js` file I tried to write the following code so that the function is overwritten but unfortunately does not work.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, modal, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        closeModal: function (element) {
            console.log("override works");    
        }
    };
});
```

Can you tell me please where is wrong and how can I override this function?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

My `requirejs-config.js` has the following code:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/web/js/modal/modal':'Bhavin_GDPR/js/view/modal/modal'
        }
    }
};
```

I create a file with name `modal.js` in the following path `app/code/Bhavin/GDPR/view/frontend/web/js/view/modal/modal.js`

Content `modal.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, modal, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        closeModal: function (element) {
            console.log("override works");
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: any error ??????

Comment: I have no error, it just does not work

Comment: override this js using theme or custom module ???

Comment: I use a custom module to override this function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best practice is to use mixins.

I also note that `requirejs-config.js` is wrong. We don't need `web` folder in the path.

```
Magento_Ui/web/js/modal/modal => Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal
```

Using mixins:

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/mixins/modal/modal': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/mixins/modal/modal.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'text!ui/template/modal/modal-popup.html',
    'text!ui/template/modal/modal-slide.html',
    'text!ui/template/modal/modal-custom.html',
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/key-codes',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, _, template, popupTpl, slideTpl, customTpl, keyCodes) {

    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mage.modal', widget, {
            /**
             * Close modal.
             * * @return {Element} - current element.
             */
            closeModal: function () {
                console.log('Alert Here');
                var that = this;

                this._removeKeyListener();
                this.options.isOpen = false;
                this.modal.one(this.options.transitionEvent, function () {
                    that._close();
                });
                this.modal.removeClass(this.options.modalVisibleClass);

                if (!this.options.transitionEvent) {
                    that._close();
                }

                return this.element;
            }
        });
        return $.mage.modal;
    };
});
```

**Testing:**

[image]

Comment: thanks, this works !!!

Comment: Thanks, solution worked in Magento 2.4.1 as well.